# Pandas: create new column from old, add values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = 'filename.csv'
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df 

        one       two     three four   five
a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  bar   True
b       NaN  1.224234  7.823421  bar  False
c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  bar  False
d       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN   True
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  bar   True
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bar  False
```

I would simply like to create a new column 'oneplus20' such that I add the float `20.0` to each cell in column 'one'. So, I try

```
df['oneplus20'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['one'] + 20, axis=1)
```

This doesn't work. I'm confused why it doesn't.

What is the correct way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['oneplus20'] = df['one'] + 20.0
```

demo:

```
In [36]: df['oneplus20'] = df['one'] + 20.0

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
        one       two     three four   five  oneplus20
a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  bar   True  20.469112
b       NaN  1.224234  7.823421  bar  False        NaN
c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  bar  False  18.864368
d       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN   True        NaN
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  bar   True  20.119209
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bar  False  17.895431
```

or if you want to replace NaN's with zeroes:

```
In [45]: df['oneplus20'] = df['one'].fillna(0) + 20.0

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
        one       two     three four   five  oneplus20
a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  bar   True  20.469112
b       NaN  1.224234  7.823421  bar  False  20.000000
c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  bar  False  18.864368
d       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN   True  20.000000
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  bar   True  20.119209
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bar  False  17.895431
```